# Lazarus, How to detect in a custom component if the current project is been closed?

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I am writing a custom component to Lazarus IDE and I need to detect in the 'destructor' of it when it is been destroyed by the user or when it is been destroyed by the Lazarus IDE when is closing.

Below is a draft idea.

```
destructor TNewCompoent.Destroy;
begin
  if(IDE.IsClosing)then
    ...
  else
    ...;

  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Thanks a lot.

**Edit (07-05-2017)**

My question was not completely correct; so I edited it.
The point is that I am not asking about *“When the IDE was closing”*; I really need to know *“When the current project is been closed”*.

**My problem:**
When a project is been closed the Lazarus’s IDE free the components that you are using; and of course, each one of the components execute their destructor procedure; In that way, if you are developing a custom component the use the destructor procedure to do something in designing time (specially with pointers or FreeAndNil) this code will be executed and  it would be a problem(It is a problem to my project).

I found some examples for designer events on http://wiki.freepascal.org/Extending_the_IDE and I’m trying to register the handler  LazarusIDE.AddHandlerOnProjectClose(@myprocedure) but is not working.

Maybe I am not thinking the best and secure choice to design my component.

Anyway, thanks a lot and if you have an idea about it I will thank you.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why you'd need to know that the IDE was closing. I suspect that the entire premise of this question is wrong.

Comment: As @David said: it should not matter why an object is being destroyed. Only *that* it is being destroyed should matter.

Comment: @David and Rudy, Thank you for answering so quickly.
I edited the question and I explain in more detail.

Comment: Your question might be, "how can I tell when my code is executing at designtime?"